# Generate a new random number and store it in an array and retrieve array value

Tags: arrays, c, random

I am new to C language. When I try to generate a new number, I get the same random number every time. Also, I am trying to store the random number to a pre-declared array in the for loop, and retrieve it from another for loop, but the integer doesn't store in the array correctly.

How do I correctly generate a new random number every time, and how to store integer in the array?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    int randNum[4] = {0,0,0,0};       
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    { 
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            randNum[i] = rand() % 100;
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", randNum[j]);
            }
            exit(0);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

`printf` function prints the following in each loop:

```
84      0       0       0 
0       84      0       0 
0       0       84      0 
0       0       84      0
```

Comment: Perhaps call `srand()` in each thread with something different: `srand(time(NULL) + i);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks, this would work

Comment: @SamMason thanks, this works

Answer (score 0):

Each thread could use a seperate state for the random number generator.

Call `srand()` with something different near the start of each thread.  E.g.:

```
srand(time(NULL) + i);
```